# SQL Server Profiler Error while login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-profiler

It's an fresh install of SQL Server 2008 R2 trial on my local development machine and I'm able to connect the server through SQL Server Management Studio. But when I tried to connect the server through SQL Server Profiler I got the following error:

TITLE: Connect to Server

---

Cannot connect to myserver.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The initialization string specified does not conform to specificiation
 (pfutil)

---

BUTTONS:

OK

---

**Edit**

Results of SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition') is as following:

Enterprise Evaluation Edition

I had tried with both Authentications (Windows Authentication and SQL Authentication) and got the same error for both modes.

When I had changed the server type to Analysis Services it got connected, but the requirement is to connect the Database Engine.

**Edit after Format:**

Finally I decide to re-format the computer and to install a fresh copy of SQL Server 2008 R2 and now the problem is gone. Now I'm able to connect the profiler with no time. :)

But I really wanna know what was the cause of that error?

Answer (score -2):

it might have something to do with the connection string you're using to connect to the profiler.
Could you post the connection string you're using to connect to the profiler?

Comment: I'm connecting the server from SQL Server Profiler, from where I can get the connection string?

Comment: When you are running a new trace for instance, what are you providing as the Server Name?

Comment: Computer Name and as I already said "I'm able to connect the server through SQL Server Management Studio"

Comment: This might sound stupid, but try using '.', instead of the 'Computer name' and then \[Instance name], if any. It some times works for me.

Comment: i tried '.' instead of the 'Computer name' and it worked for me too!